# Inputting a character to print error, but not when 0 is input in c

Tags: c, string, while-loop, atoi

I want to be able to input a character and the program would `printf("Invalid entry. \nPlease try again:\n")` but I also need to be able to input 0, I do not see why it does not work, the way I have it set up a the moment.

```
for (i=0; i<*r; i++)
{

    printf("Please enter the number of 1's in row %d :\n", (i+1));
        scanf("%s", &str);

        if(atoi(str)!=sizeof(char))
        {
            while(atoi(str)==0)
            {
                printf("Invalid entry. \nPlease try again:\n");
                    scanf("%s",str);
            }
                f = atoi(str);
        }
        else
        f=0;

        if (f>0)
        {
            printf("Please enter column location of the 1's in row %d : \n", (i+1));

                for (j=0; j<f; j++)
                {
                    scanf("%d", &g);
                        p[i][g-1]= 1;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: why did you give  `if(atoi(str)!=sizeof(char))`

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you want to happen.  Give example input and required and actual output examples.  `sizeof(char)` is always equal to 1 by definition.

Comment: @ch3rub7 when i did `if(atoi(str) ==sizeof(char))` it wouldn't work so I tried `!=` instead, but the plan was if it was the size of a character then it would be invalid but if it was an integer and or 0 it would proceed to `else f=0` or `if(f>0)`

Comment: @Clifford thank you I did not know that

Comment: I tried cutting my finger nails with a chainsaw. That did not work as I explained to the ambulance driver. After a and e I used the nail clippers. Is that how you  program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atoi()` always returns zero if the string does not start with valid decimal digits, so cannot be used to distinguish between invalid input and a valid '0' input.

Instead use scanf() with the "%d" format specifier and check its return value:

```
int i = 0 ;
do
{
    int check = scanf( "%d", &i ) ;
    while( getchar() != '\n' ) ; // flush until end of line
    if( check == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Invalid entry. \nPlease try again:\n");
    }

} while( check == 0 ) ;

// Now work with the valid input integer value in i ...
```

Consider putting the code in a function so you don't have to repeat yourself:

```
int getIntegerInput()
{
    int i = 0 ;
    do
    {
        int check = scanf( "%d", &i ) ;
        while( getchar() != '\n' ) ; // flush until end of line
        if( check == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Invalid entry. \nPlease try again:\n");
        }

    } while( check == 0 ) ;

    return i ;
}
```

Comment: I think I understand but I have already declared `i` as a variable in my code, so are you using that same value or should I declare it as a new variable like `t`

Comment: I believe I got this to work my only issue now is it allows me to input 0, Thank you for that, but then it asks me for the column location and stays there, so it prints `Please enter column location of the 1's in row 1 :` but there are no 1's in this row

Comment: I got it to work I said that `f=getIntergerInput()` thank you

Comment: @Leo.p : The variable name is of course not critical, but if you use a function, it won't clash in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why won't you get an integer as your input and then you can get rid of converting String to Integer.

```
int num;
printf("Please enter the number of 1's in row %d :\n", (i+1));
scanf("%d", &num);
while(!num)
{
    printf("Invalid entry. \nPlease try again:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I do this and I input a character it will go into an infinity loop of printing `invalid entry`

Comment: For me it works.. maybe there is a diffrence in our working enviroment.
Did you solve it?

Comment: Sadly no but I believe your method does not work because i am already in a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

You found out why `atoi()` is bad. `atoi()` doesn't do any error reporting such as integer overflow, invalid input etc and it can't distinguish a valid `0` input and a conversion failure.

Use [`strto*l()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) functions to do the conversion as they can detect conversion failures. Your input reading can be done as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<errno.h>

....

for(;;) {

   scanf("%s", str); 
   errno=0;
   long f = strtol(str, &endp, 0);

   if (endp == str || *endp != 0 || 
      (errno == ERANGE && (f == LONG_MAX || f == LONG_MIN)) || 
      (errno != 0 && f == 0)) {
          printf("Invalid entry. \nPlease try again:\n");
   }
   else  break;
}
```